# how to sort a string array by alphabet?

Tags: c#, sorting, arrays

I've got a array of many strings. How can I sort the strings by alphabet?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to use the [`Array.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx) method.

```
Array.Sort(myArray)
```

There are many overloads, some which take custom comparers (classes or delegates), but the default one should do the sorting alphabetically (ascending) as you seem to want.

Comment: +1 for mentioning its only the default behaviour.  It won't sort reverse alphabetically, you need to trick it or implement your own sort.

Comment: Or just .Sort() if they are in a List

Comment: +1 Excellent answer, for more complex sorting I would take a look at the IComparable interface or Linq's Sort expression

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program    
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] a = new string[]
        {
            "Egyptian",
            "Indian",
            "American",
            "Chinese",
            "Filipino",
        };
        Array.Sort(a);
        foreach (string s in a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Array.Sort also provides a Predicate-Overload. You can specify your sorting-behaviour there:

```
Array.Sort(myArray, (p, q) => p[0].CompareTo(q[0]));
```

You can also use LINQ to Sort your array:

```
string[] myArray = ...;
string[] sorted = myArray.OrderBy(o => o).ToArray();
```

LINQ also empoweres you to sort a 2D-Array:

```
string[,] myArray = ...;
string[,] sorted = myArray.OrderBy(o => o[ROWINDEX]).ThenBy(t => t[ROWINDEX]).ToArray();
```

The default sorting-behaviour of LINQ is also alphabetically. You can reverse this by using OrderByDescending() / ThenByDescending() instead.