# C# Sort string array alphabetically taking care of putting strings which start with capital letter first. first

Tags: c#, arrays, string, sorting, alphabetical

1) There is a Kata which states to order all string in a string array, then take the first word and add *** between each letter: https://www.codewars.com/kata/sort-and-star

2) For example:

(1) It is given:

```
bitcoin
take
over
the
world
maybe
who
knows
perhaps
```

(2) After ordering it:

```
bitcoin
knows
maybe
over
perhaps
take
the
who
world
```

(3) The return result is:

```
b***i***t***c***o***i***n
```

3) However the difficulty I am facing is the following: How we can express 'order first the words which start with capital letter'?

4) I have tried the following code:

```
using System;
public class Kata
{
  public static string TwoSort(string[] s)
  {
  foreach(string str in s){
    Console.WriteLine(str);
  }
  Console.WriteLine("");
  Array.Sort(s);
  foreach(string str in s){
    Console.WriteLine(str);
  }

  Console.WriteLine("");

  string firstWord = s[0];
  string result = "";


  foreach(char letter in firstWord){
    result += letter + "***";

  }
  Console.WriteLine(result.Substring(0, result.Length - 3));
    return result.Substring(0, result.Length - 3);
  }  
}
```

5) For example:

(1) It is given the following array:

```
Lets
all
go
on
holiday
somewhere
very
cold
```

(2) After ordering it:

```
all
cold
go
holiday
Lets
on
somewhere
very
```

(3) Current wrong result:

```
a***l***l
```

(4) Expected correct result:

```
L***e***t***s
```

I have also read:

[how to sort a string array by alphabet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148767/how-to-sort-a-string-array-by-alphabet)

[Sorting an array alphabetically in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636554/sorting-an-array-alphabetically-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should *specify the comparer*, e.g. (*Linq* solution):

```
  string[] source = new string[] {
    "Lets",
    "all",
    "go",
    "on",
    "holiday",
    "somewhere",
    "very",
    "cold",
  };

  // StringComparer.Ordinal: order by Ascii values; capital letters < small letters 
  var ordered = source
    .OrderBy(item => item, StringComparer.Ordinal);

  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", ordered));
```

Outcome:

```
  Lets, all, cold, go, holiday, on, somewhere, very
```

To obtain the desired outcome (in case you insist on ordering), you can put

```
  var result = string.Join("***", source
    .OrderBy(item => item, StringComparer.Ordinal) 
    .First()
    .Select(c => c)); // <- turn string into IEnumerable<char> 

  Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
  L***e***t***s
```

In case you want to keep on using your current code, change `Array.Sort(s);` into

```
  Array.Sort(s, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the Ordinal string comparer to short the result by capital letter then lowercase letter.

```
Array.Sort(s, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a kind of Class with Feature like "Name", You can use the following

```
if (isAscend)
    List1.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
else
    List1.Sort((x, y) => -x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
```

You can get a the Class List of sort by "Name".